# How to differentiate between two LINE friends with the same name?

Tags: line

Most users of the LINE messaging app have nicknames and profile pictures showing cats or characters.
Also, people switch names and pictures often, and profiles contain almost no info.

As a consequence, it can be very difficult to remember who is who:

---

[image: LINE Friends with same name]

---

Is there any way to differentiate between the two?
The long-press menu does not reveal any labelling/metadata option.
In the UI there is no visible ID or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to rename your contacts:

1. Run the app
2. Select a contact
3. Select their name in the panel that appears
4. Click the pen icon as seen in the screenshot below
5. Edit their name to add for instance "(colleague)" or "(from the gym)"

[image: LINE rename contact]